# hello, i am getting an error with this code. error [list index out of range]

Tags: python

I am trying to use key list elements as keys and test_list elements as values and create a new dictionary dict.

```py
test_list = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3,"d",4,"f",5]
key_list = ["name", "number"]
dic = {}

for i in range(0,len(test_list),2):
    for j in range(i,i+2):
        dic[key_list[j]] = test_list[j]
        
           
        
print(dic)
```

Comment: Why do you think it would stay inside the ranges for the lists? `j` goes from `test_list`’s length forward and indexes a list with a lot less items.

Comment: `i` goes up to `len(test_list)`, and `j` goes up to `i+2`. So `test_list[j]` is out of bounds. Also `key_list[j]` goes way out of bounds, because `key_list` only contains 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you meant to do:

```
for i in range(0,len(test_list) - 1 ,2):
    for j in range(i,i+2):
        dic[key_list[j%2] + str(i//2)] = test_list[j]
```

3 notes: (1) - `key_list` is of size `2`, so I changed the indexing to `j%2`. (2) - Your inner loop runs up to `i+1`, so you need your outer loop to run one less iteration. (3) - a dictionary only contains one value per key, so I've added  `+ str(i//2)` to the key, because I assume you want all the values and not just the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the help..